# CkEditor - Image Link URL issue

Tags: ckeditor

I'm using CkEditor to design the page, I am using image properties, the link used in image is not getting saved when **"OK"** button is clicked.

image Link :

**Working**

```
https://www.google.fr/maps/place/paris
```

**Not Working**

```
https://www.google.fr/maps/place/%Addresse%
```

here the **%Addresse%**, value will be filled on form open dynamically, but while designing the ckeditor , this URL in Image link is not getting saved.

Please can anyone help me !!!

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to reproduce the issue. On my system (ckeditor 4.4.3) it worked.